# Google Datastore - BadValueError

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

My form element is a number input as such:

```
<input class="form-control" type="number" value="10" name="foot_length">
```

The property is defined in the model as follows:

```
clin_length = ndb.IntegerProperty()
```

When I run the code on AppEngine(local) and try to put to the datastore I get this error:

```
BadValueError: Expected integer, got u'10'
```

All other types are doing the same thing except the StringProperty() - thats the only type working without this error.

So I've set everything in the model to StringProperty for now so it submits the form to datastore.

Is my form element passing the wrong type to the datastore? Is there something else I'm not understanding or missing?